# Reduce the size of a bitmap to a specified size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage, image-compression

I want to reduce the size of a bitmap to 200kb exactly. I get an image from the sdcard, compress it and save it to the sdcard again with a different name into a different directory. Compression works fine (3 mb like image is compressed to around 100 kb). I wrote the following lines of code for this:

```
String imagefile ="/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0530.jpg";
Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(imagefile, 300, 300);

//this method compresses the image and saves into a location in sdcard
    Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){
           
         BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
             
            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);
             
            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
             if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
             {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
             } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
             }
            }
             
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   
            byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
            //this gives the size of the compressed image in kb
            long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length / 1024; 
            
            try {
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mediaAppPhotos/compressed_new.jpg"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
         return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: change width and height of that image..

Comment: you mean to make the image 200x200?

Comment: yeah, as per you want 200kb.. try until you get your result..

Comment: ok, if I give a constant width and a height, will the images be of the same size always?, I have already done that: ShrinkBitmap(imagefile, 300, 300)

Comment: no, change width and height according to your size.. if you get 100kb on 300*300 then for making size 200kb, raise both width and height..

Comment: 200 x 200 = 81kb
300 x 300 = 81kb
350 x 350 = 81kb
400 x 300 = 310kb
400 x 400 = 310kb
Above are the values that I get, doesn't seem to be hitting 200kb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31304/discussion-between-segi-and-tharakanirmana)

Comment: @Kalpesh - see the answer, I answered it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I found an answer that works perfectly for me:

```
/**
 * reduces the size of the image
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

calling the method:

```
Bitmap converetdImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 500);
```

Where `photo` is your bitmap

Comment: This function will reduce the bitmap size if its larger, but what about the smaller bitmaps. Will they be enlarged as per the specification?

Comment: Why it gives be black bitmap?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana what is maxSize? in your method calling is 500, 500 kb or 500 mb?

Comment: The Max is referring to the Width and height, not the size.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean)

Comment: @TharakaNirmana 500 mb maybe not but this could be 500kb 500KB 500ko ...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. Is `maxSize` size of image in pixels or file size in Kilobytes as you wanted? I'm also looking for a similar solution but this is the closest I've come and yet I can't seem to understand what that method is doing in relation to the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22882877/3125020

This has better implementation

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution that limits image quality without changing `width` and `height`. The main idea of this approach is to compress bitmap inside the loop while output size is bigger than `maxSizeBytesCount`. Credits to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11061280/4333811) for the answer. This code block shows only the logic of reducing image quality:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int currSize;
        int currQuality = 100;

        do {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, currQuality, stream);
            currSize = stream.toByteArray().length;
            // limit quality by 5 percent every time
            currQuality -= 5;

        } while (currSize >= maxSizeBytes);
```

Here is the full method:

```
public class ImageUtils {

    public byte[] compressBitmap(
            String file, 
            int width, 
            int height,
            int maxSizeBytes
    ) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap;

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
            {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
            } else {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
            }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int currSize;
        int currQuality = 100;

        do {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, currQuality, stream);
            currSize = stream.toByteArray().length;
            // limit quality by 5 percent every time
            currQuality -= 5;

        } while (currSize >= maxSizeBytes);

        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not so good approach, compression is demanding operation. It would be nice if we could predict quality and compress bitmap only once. Still, creative thinking.

Comment: I wish that the solution you describe exists, but I think it is impossible with JPEG :(

Comment: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference" in             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, currQuality, stream);

Comment: the previous solution enter infinitive loop 
just take " ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();" inside the loop

Answer (score -1):

The method by @TharakaNirmana works fine, maxSize is in Kylobytes

Example:

```
fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap? {
    var width = image.width
    var height = image.height
    val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize
        height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
    } else {
        height = maxSize
        width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
}
```

Usage:

```
bitmap.let {
    val data = it.value

    if (data != null) {

        var image = viewModel.getResizedBitmap(data, 170)
        Log.d ("bitmap size", image!!.byteCount.toString()) ...
```

Answer

> 2021-12-18 12:38:11.218 25502-25502/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 67200
> 2021-12-18 12:39:11.673 25745-25745/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 67200
> 2021-12-18 12:39:14.511 25745-25745/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 90000
> 2021-12-18 12:39:20.423 25745-25745/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 67200
> 2021-12-18 12:39:40.112 25907-25907/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 120000
> 2021-12-18 12:39:43.322 25907-25907/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 120000
> 2021-12-18 12:39:47.314 25907-25907/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 160000
> 2021-12-18 12:40:17.231 26069-26069/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 115600
> 2021-12-18 12:40:19.583 26069-26069/com.jdsalasc.sophosSolutions D/bitmap size: 86360

how you see, the bytes size never comes over 150 kb

Thank you Zoe and TharakaNirmana c: