# How to set Limit Upload Image from Android to Database MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

Sir I have problem, when I want set `LIMIT` to `UPLOAD IMAGE` in KB (kilobytes), example 200KB.

```
private void uploadImage(){
    if (bitmap.getByteCount() > 7 * 1024 * 1024){
        H.T(AddFotoActivity.this,"Image Maks 200KB");
    }
}
```

I try that code but, I can only upload 110KB and when I try upload 116KB it can't upload.
How to upload 200KB file sir? I don't know how to calculate 7*1024*1024

Comment: 1024 Bytes are 1 kiloByte. So **200kB * 1024B = 204800 Bytes**

Comment: BUT, bitmaps are bigger in memory than the image file. So probabli an image file of 200k, would be much more when it gets open as a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
/**
 * reduces the size of the image
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

use it like:

```
Bitmap scaledImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 300); //here 300 is maxsize
```

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Sample_photographs)

For highest quality images (Q=100), about 8.25 bits per color pixel is required

So, for `Q=100` on an `300x300` image, that would result in (300 * 300) px * 8.25 bits/px = 741,500 bits = ~ 91 kB which is surely less than 200KB

you can try for other dimension too..

you can also try to make an image using the bitmap and compare the actual size of the image..

here is the code:

```
 //create a file to write bitmap data
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Your code is for widht and heigh resizing. So it doesn't mean 200k file resizing... Also, he is asking for another problem I think..

Comment: ok i may be wrong ...but take a look at this before give downvote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954109/reduce-the-size-of-a-bitmap-to-a-specified-size-in-android

Comment: Ok @rafsanahmad007 then link the answer and not only copy the code please.

Comment: Although he is asking about how to calculate size and upload. Not about resizing.

Comment: so what should I do sir for set limit upload image 200KB ?

Comment: call this method Bitmap scaledImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 300); //it will give you a 300X300 image which is less than 200KB..then you can upload image to your MYSQL database

Comment: see the edited answer..if it works don't forget to accept it

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 thanks sir that worked, amazing (om telolet om)

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 sir i try to upload 17KB, but when i download the image from database, the the size of image is 25KB..
why the image became large ?
how to bypass the convert image iif the image <200KB ??
i try with your sourcecode

Comment: i think you server side do some modification on the image bitmap..bytes ..thats why it is large...my code only takes a bitmap as parameter and resize it before upload it to server

Comment: you can ask question how to check image size after modification from the server..