# Can't show image in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem, i load an image(4128x3096) from storage and i want show it on screen.

But after run, my screen is blank (screen white)

But when i load another image(1080x720), it worked and show image on screen

Now, i want show and fill an image(4128x3096) on screen

How to do it?

This is my code:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(patchFile)
val matrix = Matrix()
matrix.postRotate(90F)
val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap)
```

LogCat:

```
    05-29 11:27:47.194 32471-32507/com.example.minhduc.aicam W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3096x4128, max=4096x4096)
    Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3096x4128, max=4096x4096)
05-29 11:27:48.970 32471-32493/com.example.minhduc.aicam W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.widget.Toast$TN$2) {a8d7afe} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.widget.Toast$TN$2) {a8d7afe} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:643)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:612)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:582)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:519)
        at android.os.Message.sendToTarget(Message.java:416)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.hide(Toast.java:414)
        at android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub.onTransact(ITransientNotification.java:57)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Comment: please post LogCat so we can check what's the issue

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954109/reduce-the-size-of-a-bitmap-to-a-specified-size-in-android to reduce the size of the bitmap so that it will get loaded in `ImageView`

Comment: this is my logcat: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3096x4128, max=4096x4096), i updated my question

Comment: decodeFile() will return null if the bitmap would become too big for available memory. Better use images with lower resolution. Or scale down during load. Have a look at the options parameter.

Comment: just pre-scale image before loading.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your image size is too large just because image view not loading the image.

Better way use library like `picasso`, `Glide` or `Universal image loader` which will load image perfectly otherwise resize your bitmap.

Comment: I will look at those libraries now